# Pascal : External File Can't be updated

Tags: external, pascal, freepascal

I have an issue on rewriting my .txt file, did I made some mistake? The program run smoothly though. This is a piece of my library.

```
//global variable
uses utheatre;
var loadUDT:TheatreUDT;
//utheatre library
type
TheatreUDT = record
    Member:text;
end;

procedure load_main(var loadUDT : TheatreUDT);
begin
        load_Member(loadUDT.Member);
end;

procedure load_Member(var Member:text);
begin
    assign (Member,'Data/Member.txt');
end;

procedure regis(var loadUDT:TheatreUDT);
var
    s:string;
begin
    rewrite(loadUDT.Member);
    write('> Input Username : ');
    readln(s);
    write(loadUDT.Member,s);
    write(loadUDT.Member,' | ');
    write('> Input Password : ');
    readln(s);
    write(loadUDT.Member,s);
    writeln(loadUDT.Member,' | 100000');
    writeln('> Registration Successful');
end;

procedure exit(var loadUDT:TheatreUDT; var bool_main:boolean);
    begin
        close(loadUDT.Member);
        bool_main := False;
    end;
```

I expected the output inside my notepad will be

> username | password | 100000

but it seems that the Member.txt is not updated. Thanks before.

EDIT : This is My Main Program

```
begin
    bool_main := True;
    while(bool_main) do begin
        write('> ');
        readln(input_main);
        case input_main of
            'load' : load_main(loadUDT);
            'register' : regis(loadUDT);
            'exit' : exit();
        end;
    end;
end.
```

N.B. I found out that when I add "close(loadUDT.Member)" inside my "regis procedure", it worked, however it didn't work when i insert the "close(loadUDT.Member)" inside the "exit procedure". Any ideas why? Thanks again before.

Comment: Please show the calls to your procedures, otherwise it may happen that no I/O is acually done. Even then 'updated' may be wrong, because the file is always rewritten. Are you sure that you look in the 'data' subdirectory?

Comment: @gammatester edited. actually I've checked the "data" subdirectory and it created Member.txt in it but has nothing in it(0 bytes).

Comment: Why the call of `exit()` without parameters? Does this actually compile and work? BTW `exit` is a standard procedure. And may be without parameters `system.exit` is called and leave your procedure without closing.

Comment: @gammatester actualy it worked somehow, even though `exit()` need loadUDT and  bool_main parameter. Also, It changes bool_main to false and ended the program. Weird, but It gave compilation error when I added parameters into `exit()`

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the answer already. exit() is reserved. Sorry Guys.
N.B. Thanks to @gammatester